# Google Campaigns tracking with Spring Web flow

Tags: spring, google-analytics, spring-webflow

I am using Spring Web Flow for one of my clients and by default the Post-Redirect-Get (PRG) configuration is switched on for the website. The client now wants to enable Google Campaigns to allow them to track the campaigns they launching. But, due to the PRG configuration, the information is lost during the redirect. We have already tried to switch-off the PRG configuration but it results in issues in other flow. Is there is any solution which has been suggested for Spring Web flow to track the Google Campaigns.

Thanks in advance.

P.S: We are currently using spring-webflow-2.0.9 and spring MVC 2.5.6

Comment: Is your website already tracked by Google Analytics ? May you please provide more details about parameters that are lost ? Isn't there an alternate option like cookies (like for GA) to track Campaign ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have been able to solve the problem by doing a workaround.The steps are given below.

1. To add a check in the application filter to look for all the Google Campaigns related data  like utm_source / utm_medium / utm_campaign.
2. Once found them in filter, then store it in Application Cookie, on the server side.
3. In the page where the tracking needs to be added, add the JavaScript to check if these Cookies have been set.
4. If the cookies are set then we called _setCampValue() method, using the Javascript mentioned in the link [extga.js](http://blog.intlock.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/extga.js)
5. This JS sets the __utmz cookie, which Google Analytic uses for identifying the campaigns.

Please find the link of [blog](http://blog.intlock.com/_setcampvalues-for-google-analytics/) from which we have taken the javascript to modify the __utmz cookie used by Google Campaigns.

Thanks.

Comment: It would be much better if you could use the getLinkerUrl function from GAs cross domain tracking - that way you do not only keep the campaign parameters, but you also keep the visitor session intact. We use that to create a Url with all the utm and session parameters and send that to our redirect script were we pluck the parameters from the url and append them to the proper redirect url. No idea if this is even possible with Spring Web Flow (we're a PHP shop) but it would save you from fiddling with the google cookie.